# What is the hotkey to perform a replace in the Find in Files dialog?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Hovering over the Replace button does not show me a hotkey in the `Find in Files` dialog.

What is the hotkey to do so? Otherwise, how can I give it one?

[image]

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. Could you post an image showing what button you are trying to activate, and include in it some of the text you're searching and replacing?

Comment: @MattDMo done. "What is the hotkey to perform a global find and replace".

Comment: I don't get it, you want to submit the replacement, by 'clicking' the button in the image - 'replace' - with the keyboard?

Comment: This is actually the `Find In Files` dialog, not the global `Find and Replace` toolbar.

Comment: @MattDMo, Ah that would help find the answer wouldn't it. Thanks! "How do I perform a replace in the `Find In Files` dialog via hotkey?"

Comment: @shub: yes, I want to "click" the button in the image via keyboard.

Comment: @shub pressing enter should search all files for your search query, not replace..

Comment: @YujiTomita Now I see what I was overlooking :)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will do a replace all (whilst in the replace panel)

Comment: Not on a global find and replace. Let me update the Q.